# jpa 2 hibernate limit (max results) to a CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

maybe it's a silly question but I cannot find the answer in the docs:
How can set a limit to the CriteriaQuery using JPA2?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A CriteriaQuery is not an executable Query.  You need to create a TypedQuery first using `EntityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)`.  You can then set the max results of this and execute it.

Answer (score 12):

You could define the offset/limit like this:

```
return em.createQuery(query)
     .setFirstResult(offset) // offset
     .setMaxResults(limit) // limit
     .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
em.createQuery(criteria).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(max).getResultList();
```