# Paginating a JPA 2 criteria query

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is it possible to paginate a JPA 2 [criteria query](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html), as you can with in Hibernate with setFirstResult and setMaxResults?

If not, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679131/jpa-2-hibernate-limit-max-results-to-a-criteriaquery) question "[jpa 2 hibernate limit (max results) to a CriteriaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679131/jpa-2-hibernate-limit-max-results-to-a-criteriaquery)"

> A CriteriaQuery is not an executable
>   Query. You need to create a TypedQuery
>   first using
>   EntityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).
>   You can then set the max results of
>   this and execute it.

Comment: Thanks. I'd searched, but that question didn't appear in the results for "pagination".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with usage of entity manager and passing a criteria query as parameter:

```
List<?> results = em.createQuery(criteria).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(5).getResultList();
```