# Hibernate/JPA How to fetch 200 Records only

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have made a DAO method to access the DB and get the results based on STATUS=TECHERROR. The sample code is as -

```
public void loadTable() {
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyDTO.class);
Root<MyDTO> dashBoard = criteriaQuery.from(MyDTO.class);

ParameterExpression<String> p = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class);
criteriaQuery.select(dashBoard).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(dashBoard.get("status"), p));

TypedQuery<MyDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter(p, "TECHERR");

List<MyDTO> MyDtoList = query.getResultList();}
```

This is working perfectly fine. Now I want only 200 rows/records to be fetched.

I tried solutions provided at this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679131/jpa-2-hibernate-limit-max-results-to-a-criteriaquery)

but it is not working.
Snippet of the error is -

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

Please help me find a way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: did you try `query.setMaxResult(200);` ??

Comment: _query.setMaxResults(200);_ as advised on the linked thread. Posting some exception is pointless without the stack trace and NESTED EXCEPTION